# YA novel about dragons, melting gold, and werewolves

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for something I read in High School about six years ago.

It was about a teenage girl who could communicate with dragons in some fashion or was otherwise just connected to dragons in some way. She goes on a long journey to meet a king or something, and along the way meets a stoic, bad-boy type guy. He's either a werewolf or a hunter, but I remember he had oddly-colored eyes and dressed in furs.

Somewhere along the way they meet an evil tyrant who I believe was trying to destroy all of dragon-kind. They eventually fight him, there's some sneaking around and then his castle falls to pieces and the villain is defeated when hot molten gold is dumped on him by a dragon.

I thought either the word "Gold" or something describing gold was in the title, but I've tried Glimmer, Glint, Glow, Shimmer, Shine, Sheen, Twinkle, Luster, and Radiance and nothing that sounds even remotely like this has come up. The cover was golden too, and might have had a woman on it. It was shelved in the A though the H (by authors last name, of course) section of this library's fiction side.

Edit: I don't recall any characters names, unfortunately. It was a new release six years ago, in my 2010-2011 High School year. The "Gold" theme of the novel featured heavily on the cover. I believe the villain was referred to as the "Lord" of something, too. The bad-boy character might not of necessarily been a werewolf but some other shapeshifter type, and I think he meets the main character when he mistakes her for something else and attacks her.

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1022209.Song_in_the_Silence?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Dragons-Dragon-Chronicles-Susan-Fletcher/dp/1416997121?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Shadow-Scale-Seraphina-Rachel-Hartman/dp/0375866574?ie=UTF8&amp%3Bcamp=217145&amp%3Bcreative=399349&amp%3BcreativeASIN=0375866574&amp%3BlinkCode=as2&amp%3Btag=boorio-20&redirect=true&ref_=as_li_tf_il?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure I haven't read Seraphina, I'd remember that. The other two don't look too familiar either.

Comment: Have a look at my checklist [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add any more detail. The name of the main character would be key, as would some more detail about the characters and any dialogue that they said.